# Errors with Background Style on a TextBlock

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I have following style in a xaml file:

```
<Style x:Key="LabelText"
             TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe Black"/>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFB3B4C1"/>
                <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF3B596E"/>
            </Style>
```

Unfortunately, the

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF3B596E"/>
```

isn't recognized by Visual Studio, so my xaml webpage won't load. If I remove the background setter it works, but I need this background.

Is there some sort of workaround to fix this issue?

Comment: You should probably mention this is Silverlight... this works fine in WPF, because the Background property is defined in FrameworkElement, not Control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Silverlight the `TextBlock` class doesn't have a `Background` property, its always transparent. If you want it to have a background color, put it in another control, like a `Border`, on which you set the background color.

Another option is to use a `Label` instead of a `TextBlock`.

Comment: I have an awful lot of elements using this style, is it possible to put a border "around the style" instead of having to rewrite nearly all my code?

Comment: @Matthias, no, it's not possible. And you can't put it in a template since a TextBlock is not a Control and doesn't have a template... The easiest way is probably to replace the TextBlocks with Labels

Answer (score 0):

You could take a jQuery-like approach, and walk the visual tree when the page loads to wrap all textblocks with a border (with the appropriate style applied).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a `ContentControl` instead of a `TextBlock`, no need to wrap the visual then.

```
<ContentControl Content='MyText' Background="#FF3B596E" />
```